# Django How to know if queryset is cached or not? using johnnycache

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, django-queryset

I just discovered johnnycache and it looks awesome. I pip-installed it and added the few lines of code to my settings just as the documentation instructed as follows.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'johnny.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:8000',
        'JOHNNY_CACHE': True,
    }
}
JOHNNY_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = 'jc_efl'
```

and the Middleware settings..

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
    'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',
... }
```

I loaded my site in my browser and it runs fine and there isn't any noticeable difference in load-times.

I want to know how can I know if my retrieved queries are actually coming from the cache or not.

I looked up on Google and SO and a lot is mentioned about view/template caching where they use the commented-timestamp method of getting it done. But I believe, that does not apply here.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for the same thing.  I think they intend for you to use the signals

`johnny.cache.signals.qc_hit` - fired after a cache hit

and

`johnny.cache.signals.qc_miss` - fired after a cache miss

from [johnny cache docs](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/queryset_cache.html#signals)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) (DDT) to see the queries run by each request. If the DDT shows queries being run, it means they are cache misses.